# unexpected behavior of apollo link retry on 400 error

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, vue-apollo

`description: Attempt an operation multiple times if it fails due to network or server errors.`

I have used apollo-link-retry to retry calls on the occurrence of server errors(5xx).
But when 400 error(bad request) is occurring it retrying which is expected to retry in server error only.
Does network error means all client errors(4xx) and server errors(5xx)?
How to stop retrying on errors other than 5xx?

Comment: The question is clear now, please re-open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of Apollo Client, there are two types of errors -- GraphQL errors (those returned inside the `errors` array in the response) and network errors. Any request that returns a status other than 200 is considered to have encountered a network error. The default RetryLink configuration is not that granular -- it only cares about whether a network error occurred, not what kind of error occurred. If you want to *not* retry on certain errors, provide a `retryIf` function to the `attempts` configuration as shown in the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/retry/):

```
  attempts: {
    retryIf: (error, _operation) => {
      // return true or false depending on the properties on error
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: do you mean to say that all status codes other than 2xx are considered as network error?

Comment: I guess technically it's [any status 300 or above](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/0340c48429b20f621d552af748527798bf6f26c5/src/link/http/parseAndCheckHttpResponse.ts#L30).